# IE rendering in Quirks even when doctype is set and is W3 verified

Tags: html, xhtml, quirks-mode

This is the doctype that I'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

The code is 100% verified, but I know that IE is still rendering it using Quriks.  What gives?

Link to test code: http://pdme.com/test/

Comment: `X-UA-Compatible` header? Comments before the doctype? We can't find the reason without a link to the website.

Comment: No comments or spacing before the doctype declaration. http://pdme.com/test/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've already said, the `<!-- comments -->` before the doctype trigger quirks mode in IE<=9.

Comment: Thanks, I got it figured out!  I'm using php to build out the site, and I wasn't looking at the actual page. <?php include("head.html"); ?> was after my comments.  Thanks for pointing that out!  DOH!